# Ng add @nrwl/workspace throws Cannot read property 'paths' of undefined

Tags: angular, web-applications, monorepo, nrwl

I just make a project with the angular cli and then run the command "ng add @nrwl/workspace" to change it to a nrwl workspace. But I am getting the following error "Cannot read property 'paths' of undefined".

I searched a bit in the internet and found out that someone had a similar error but his was that in angular.json test was missing I have everything needed in my angular.json.

Can someone maybe look at my json file and say what could possibly cause this error. I am using th e latest version of both nrwl and angular

Angula.json

```
   {
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "moniesta-admin": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/moniesta-admin",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "moniesta-admin:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "moniesta-admin:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "moniesta-admin:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "moniesta-admin:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "moniesta-admin:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }},
  "defaultProject": "moniesta-admin"
}
```

Comment: Did that happen with v10? In case can you file an issue on the nrwl/nx repository if the problem persists with v10.

Answer (score 3):

I also encountered this kind of problem, I solved it like this: in the root directory **tsconfig.json** A `paths` parameter is required in.
like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I know it's late to answer this question but I hope this could be help.

I have experienced the same issue while trying to serve backend using both nestjs and express using Nx generate CLI (`nx g @nrwl/express:app my-app` and `nx g @nrwl/nest:app my-nest-app`. Right after run `nx server my-app`, terminal print below error

```
{
  stack: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'endsWith' of undefined\n" +
    '    at createProjectRootMappings (/Users/path-to-root/node_modules/nx/src/project-graph/file-map-utils.js:12:38)\n' +
    '    at createProjectFileMap (/Users/path-to-root/node_modules/nx/src/project-graph/file-map-utils.js:27:33)\n' +
    '    at /Users/path-to-root/node_modules/nx/src/daemon/server/project-graph-incremental-recomputation.js:92:85\n' +
    '    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)\n' +
    '    at fulfilled (/Users/path-to-root/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:115:62)\n' +
    '    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)',
  message: "Cannot read property 'endsWith' of undefined\n" +
    '\n' +
    'Because of the error the Nx daemon process has exited. The next Nx command is going to restart the daemon process.\n' +
    'If the error persists, please run "nx reset".'
}
```

Turn out there's missing line in file `project.json` generate by nx

```json
{
  "root": "packages/my-app", // add this line
  "sourceRoot": "packages/my-app/src",
  "projectType": "application",
  "targets": {
    ....
  },
  ....
}
```

Comment: Cheers! The error message should be clearer.

Comment: I've `package.json` and `workspace.json`. And upgraded `@nrwl` from `10.2.1` to `14.4.2`. I see in  `workspace.json` for the each project we have `root": "apps/xxx"`. But all the nx commands are failing with same above error. Any help would be much appricated.